# Please let me search chat messages for messages that consist solely of punctuation

Tags: feature-request, search, chat

It's [become](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3212450#3212450) [something](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3212064#3212064) [of](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3211920#3211920) [a](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3211948#3211948) [meme](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3190829#3190829) for me to express my sadness in chat with messages that consist solely of ":(".

How much of a meme?  I don't know, because [it won't let me search messages for ":("](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%3A%28&user=5145&room=35).  Even the RSS feed shares my dismay.

Please let me search for all-punctuation messages.

<sup>Also, the RSS link gives the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.</sup>

Comment: Using ":(" messages to express sadness...that's quite the meme you've come up with

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Ok, so it's more of a meme for [Wipqozn](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8350/wipqozn) to [revel in my sadness](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=3074341#3074341).

Comment: Wha???  That... That looks like a guy frowning, if you turn your head sideways!  Whoa!  See, this is why I love memes.  People are coming up with new and cute ways to interact over the innernets all the time.  Awesome meme, great job!

Comment: Laugh out loud!  Next you will come up with acronyms for common phrases that nobody else has thought to shorten yet!  Just Kidding!  Hope This Helps!  Away From Keyboard!

Comment: @JNK Hey, I am *not* one of the people who stars this stuff. I don't make the memes.